# ionic2 not sending post data

Tags: angular, ionic2

Following is a function in my auth.service.ts I am calling it from one of my pages..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public token: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {

  }
login(credentials){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(credentials);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('https://mysite.co.uk/ionlogin.php', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {

        let data = res.json();
        this.token = data.token;
        this.storage.set('token', data.token);
        resolve(data);

        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

});

}
}
```

the above login function is called successfully but it doesn't send any data. But in the console console.log(credentials) prints before post request.

> {email: "sugumar", password: "123456"}

but in the network tab in the browser, I don't see any data sent to the server.

and in the the server I am printing using

> var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));

it prints null in the network tab in the browser

I also see the following error in the console

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mysite.co.uk/ionlogin.php. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

so I added the following lines in my php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, 
    X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

but still the same problem

Comment: Do you have any errors ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO no errors bro

Comment: not related but there is a `toPromise()` method on `Observable` objects...

Comment: @n00dl3 bro I am new to ionic so please tell me how to use it

Comment: are you sure, your php  api code is working ?

Comment: yes there is no problem in that..

Comment: *”Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.”* indicates that somewhere in your frontend JavaScript code, you’re adding a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request. Remove whatever code it doing that. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header for servers to send. The only effect adding it to a request from client side will have it to break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RequestOptions` instead of sending the header as a object directly

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

public login = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type', 'application/json'});
    // JUST TOOK OFF APPEND CAUSE I LIKE THIS WAY, THERE'S NO NEED FOR YOU TO REMOVE IT.
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    this.http.post('https://mysite.co.uk/ionlogin.php', JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
    .subscribe(res => {

      let data = res.json();
      this.token = data.token;
      this.storage.set('token', data.token);

      // WHY DO YOU RESOLVE THIS TWICE? IT'LL ONLY GET THE FIRST RESOLVE
      resolve(data);
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

The `RequestOptions` module create your options based on the Fetch Spec for requisitions, maybe passing just the headers as a object is making it fail or is something missing that is provided by the request option.

Hope this helps.